# Codeigniter missing argument

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Help guys.

**This my error problem error:**

[image]

I Think i follow right tutorial, but i don't know what the wrong from my code

there is my **controllers**

```
public function edit($id){
    $where = array('id' => $id);
    $data['barang'] = $this->model_barang->edit($where,'barang')->results();
    $this->load->view('edit',$data);
}
public function update(){
    $id = $this->input->post('id');
    $jenis = $this->input->post('jenis');
    $nama = $this->input->post('nama');
    $harga = $this->input->post('harga');
    $pemasok = $this->input->post('pemasok');

    $data = array (
        'jenis' => $jenis,
        'nama'=> $nama,
        'harga' => $harga,
        'pemasok' => $pemasok
    );

    $where = array(
        'id' => $id
    );

    $this->model_barang->update($where,$data,'barang');
    redirect('barang/tampil');
}
```

and there is my **model**, i think my model is not showing any error

```
public function edit($where,$table) {
    return $this->db->get($table,$where);
}
public function update($where,$data,$table){
    $this->db->where($where);
    $this->db->update($table,$data);
}
```

Comment: to prevent warning pass default value in params, like `public function edit($id = null){/**code**/}` and handle value inside method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **need to pass the $id** to the controller.
It should be something like this `http://domain.com/barang/edit/1`